# Obtener un valor que ya fue pasado como parámetro en una vista

Tags: c#, asp.net

Debo de usar una sola vista para dos acciones: la de crear y la de editar. Esto lo controlo mediante una bandera que dependiendo del valor me pone la vista vacía o con los datos del registro seleccionado. Lo que no logro hacer es volver a obtener la bandera en la vista del formulario para volverla a mandar como parámetro a mi `ActionResult` que determina si va a hacer un `update` o un `insert`.

Esta es la forma en la que paso mis parámetros para determinar como me mostrará la vista.

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Agregar Hotel", "CrEd", "Hoteles", new { bandera = 1, id = 0 }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-lg active" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `Action`, puedes devolver un valor al `View` con el mismo valor que recibiste en la bandera por medio del `ViewBag`:

```
public ActionResult InsertaActualiza(bool bandera, int id)
{
    //Aquí va toda la lógica para el INSERT o el UPDATE
    ViewBag.Bandera = bandera;
    return View();
}
```

Ahora, en el `View` solo tienes que acceder a la variable del `ViewBag` desde donde desees utilizarla:

```
@ViewBag.Bandera
```